# How to save a table entry in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

[image]I am working on a `django` admin based project now i am stuck with a big thing.i want to add a field named `"item_issued"` in the `user_profile` model.
in the `"item issued"` field there is a table which consist of 3 column `"item_name","quantity" and "price"`.I am unable to apply this.Can u guys please help me in this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your ``UserProfile`` model and also the ``ItemIssued`` Model code here to help you out.

Comment: @KousickShanmugamNagaraj i have updated my question.i have add image which i want to show under "item_issued" field

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to add a `ForeignKey` to your `user_profile` pointing to `item_issued`. You can accomplish that by creating a new model `ItemIssued` with the fields you mentioned:

```
class ItemIssued(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Now, when you're having `ItemIssued` model you can add a `ForeignKey` to `user_profile` (I assume the model is called `UserProfile`):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     ...   # your existing fields
     item_issued = models.ForeignKey(ItemIssued)
```

After that, don't forget to run

```
 python manage.py makemigrations app
 python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: by doing this i can only select one value.but i have to select more thhan one value.i want to save a full table consist og thrreee column .i atttcached  the pic which i want to add as table

Comment: you're very unclear with your specs but from what you're telling now you want to use `models.ManyToManyField` instead of `models.ForeignKey`

Comment: i have uploaded image.which i want to add in item_issued field

Comment: i want a field named "item_issued".with a button in front of it when i click on this button it shows me a another window or pop up which consist a table with column "item_name","quantity",and "price".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point:

`models.py`:

```
class ItemIssued(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2) #use decimal field for price values.


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # some other fields..
    issued_items = models.ManyToManyField("ItemIssued", related_name="+issued_items", null=True, blank=True)
```

And if you need to use this field outside of Django Admin, `views.py`:

```
user = UserProfile.objects.get(username="ali")

new_issued_item = ItemIssued.objects.get(item_name="test_item")

user.issued_items.add(new_issued_item) #add 
user.issued_items.delete(new_issued_item) #delete

items = user.issued_items.all()  # get all issued items of user
```

i didn't test the code. But they should work.

Comment: i do not using views.py,it is only a django admin based.

Comment: it is ok. Even better. you can create your models, based on these ones. @CpVerma